# batch file that feeds one line of input of a file path to a .exe and runs the program?

Tags: c#, batch-file, console-application, exe, user-input

I wrote a console application that we want to schedule to run overnight through a scheduler, but when it starts it needs user input of a file path string that leads to a database.How would i write this batch file?

what i have is:

```
Console.WriteLine("DataBase file path:");
source = Console.ReadLine();
```

I need to automate the source and run the program.

for example:

```
 source = "C:\Users\Documents\New folder\data.mdb"
```

Thank you!

EDIT

we want to have two ways to run this program, one automated and one manual,
if anyone has any other ideas on how to do this I'm open to suggestions!

OK ANOTHER EDIT:

i have a program that needs a string of user input of a file path that leads to a database.

We want to run this program overnight, through the scheduler, and have a preset filepath string which would be taken as the user input.

We also want to be able to run the program and enter the file path string ourselves, so hard coding is not an option.

we also want to be able to run this program though the command prompt

so i was thinking of making 2 different batch files, one with preset input and one without, i just dont know how to do the preset input.

if anyone has suggestions please help

Thank you

Comment: Why are you involving a batchfile?  Why not do everything via C#?

Comment: we want to run it through command prompt

Comment: You can run a C# program via the command prompt.  It really looks like you're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: how would i automate the input?

Comment: `C:\> MyCSharpProgram.exe c:\users\docs\data.mdb`  [see link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: You keep editing your question, but not making it any clearer.  "Automated" and "manual" are not clear cut ideas.  You will have to explain *clearly* what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @abelenky how about now?

Comment: `Ira` if someone has provided you a working solution then you should mark that answer as the acceptable answer...

Answer (score 2):

If I get what you mean passing a parameter to an exe in a batch file is like this:

```
yourApp.exe "C:\Users\Documents\New folder\data.mdb"
```

Then in your app, you can check if no parameter was passed, ask the user to input the path:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
```

Comment: OP said he wants to pass the path to the application from a batch file.

Comment: @RufusL keep in mind what the OP normally wants or needs usually is not what they will always get especially in a case like this.. when this can always be done with C# alone and or cmd line parameters or setting the path at launch in a app.config file so your comment I would respectfully respond, `Think outside the box`

Comment: Fair enough, although this was not an answer when I commented... The answer has been edited since I commented, and now shows how to consume the args if they're present and how to prompt if they were missing. +1

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to interpret what you are looking for is ["input redirection"](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

```
 myProgram.exe < myInput
```

Or you may be looking for parsing some input file with CMD and getting part of first line - `for` is the way to do it in CMD files.

Note that usually parameters are passed as parameters of `Main` like

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    string source;
    if (args.Length == 1)
      source = args[0];
    else
      source = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still see absolutely no need for a batchfile.
You can do it all from C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputFile = null;

        if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].Length > 0)
        {
            inputFile = args[0];
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No command-line input detected. Please enter a filename:");
            inputFile = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Beginning Operation on file {0}", inputFile);
        /* Do Work Here */
    }
}
```

***Example Runs:***

```
C:\> myProgram.exe  data.mdb
Beginning Operation on file data.mdb


C:\> myProgram.exe
No command-line input detected. Please enter a filename:
OtherData.mdb   // <-- typed by user at keyboard
Beginning Operation on file OtherData.mdb
```